# How Can I Populate Images in Strapi from URL in MongoDB?

Tags: strapi

I have imported my json file listing products into Mongodb and created a content type in Strapi for my products. I have an array of image URL's that can only be added to my content type as json. Is there any way for Strapi to pull the images from these URL's and populate an image type field?

**URLs:**

```
   "Images": [
        {
            "Number": 1,
            "FullPath": "https://images.trader.uk/Images/18/1803/18032/180329160440003/180329160440003-1.jpg",
            "ThumbPath": "https://images.trader.uk/Images/Thumbnails/180329160440003-1-120x120.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Number": 2,
            "FullPath": "https://images.trader.uk/Images/18/1803/18032/180329160440003/180329160440003-2.jpg",
            "ThumbPath": "https://images.trader.uk/Images/Thumbnails/180329160440003-2-120x120.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Number": 3,
            "FullPath": "https://images.trader.uk/Images/18/1803/18032/180329160440003/180329160440003-3.jpg",
            "ThumbPath": "https://images.trader.uk/Images/Thumbnails/180329160440003-3-120x120.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Number": 4,
            "FullPath": "https://images.trader.uk/Images/18/1803/18032/180329160440003/180329160440003-4.jpg",
            "ThumbPath": "https://images.trader.uk/Images/Thumbnails/180329160440003-4-120x120.jpg"
        }
    ],
```

Comment: Hello! The thing you want to do is to import these images in Strapi and link them to a specific entry of your application. And then be able to manage them from the Strapi application?

Comment: Hi, yes. I kind of expected that Strapi would auto populate them with the image content type..